# Bit-code enabled error during compilation in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode9.3, iotivity

I have created static iotivity framework(release) with bit code enabled in xcode-build settings for multiple .a files (each .a file will support for all architecture like armv7,arv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64) and header files by using scripts(https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios). When I try to integrate generated iotivity framework in sample project with bit code enabled, I am getting following error when building in device. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
iotivity.framework/iotivity(OCPlatform.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have generated FAT file which will support all architecture as said above. Is there any way to create FAT file with bit code enabled using terminal.